# I need to get the first letter from a string and make it an index to an other letter from other string in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, indexing

I'm new to programming so I'm starting with a course about python, and on this course I found this exercise that I don't know how to do, so if someone could  help me

```
>def cipher(map_from, map_to, code):
   """ map_from, map_to: strings where each contain 
                          N unique lowercase letters. 
      code: string (assume it only contains letters also in map_from)
        Returns a tuple of (key_code, decoded).
        key_code is a dictionary with N keys mapping str to str where 
        each key is a letter in map_from at index i and the corresponding 
        value is the letter in map_to at index i. 
        decoded is a string that contains the decoded version 
        of code using the key_code mapping. """
```

For example,

`cipher("abcd", "dcba", "dab")` returns (order of entries in dictionary may not be the same) `({'a':'d', 'b': 'c', 'd': 'a', 'c': 'b'}, 'adc')`

Answer (score 0):

Characters are indexed starting at 0.  This should provide a hint:

```
>>> 'abcdefgh'.find('e')
4
>>> 'abcdefgh'[4]
'e'
```